# operator #+ and #- in .sbclrc

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, reader-macro

Anybody know what `#+` and `#-` operators means in `.sbclrc`? I couldn't find it in the manual. 
I see `#-` in `.sbclrc` after I installed quicklisp:

```
#-quicklisp
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp"
                                       (user-homedir-pathname))))
  (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
    (load quicklisp-init)))
```

I also see `#+` in the SBCL User Manual, but I couldn't find explanation of their functionality. Looks like something related for loading individual module.

Are they only for SBCL implementation or part of Common lisp?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's a general facility of Common Lisp, not only SBCL.

There is a variable `cl:*features*` which lists symbols for 'features' which should be present in the Lisp system currently. Typical features are: endian, implementation, subsystems, processor, extensions, Lisp dialect and more.

In a Lisp file the expression `#+quicklisp(foo)` means: read and execute `(foo)` only if the feature `quicklisp` is present in the list of features `*features*`.

In a Lisp file the expression `#-quicklisp(foo)` means: read and execute `(foo)` only if the feature `quicklisp` is NOT present in the list of features `*features*`.

This facility is often used to hide or show implementation specific code to some other Common Lisp implementation.

See the documentation:

- [Features](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/24_ab.htm)
- [Feature Expressions](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/24_aba.htm)
- [sharpsign plus](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhq.htm)
- [sharpsign minus](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhr.htm)

A typical extension is the [feature-case](https://github.com/antifuchs/mcclim/blob/master/Apps/Scigraph/dwim/feature-case.lisp) reader macro.

Answer (score 8):

They're part of the Common Lisp `READ`er. The idea is that they "hide" text unless a certain feature (often, a certain CL implementation) is (`#+`) or is not (`#-`) available.

These are probably the CL concept most like the C/C++ idea of "textual macros" -- conceptually and pragmatically, they are very similar to something like

```
 #ifdef __MSVC12__
 #ifndef __cplusplus__
```

...and the like. They literally hide bits of incoming cource code from the `READ`er, so they're never lexed - parsed - interpreted - compiled - evaluated - interned - nada. They simply cease to exist if the CL implementation you're running lacks a feature / is the "wrong" implementation / whatever flag.

Comment: Do you know where I can find the documentation for this? I'm wondering if there is other READer features I don't know about.

Comment: In general, anything with a leading # is something special in the reader; check out the CLHS index under #, starting from http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/X_Mast_9.htm